# Generating dynamic JSTree - JStree displays only when the database name is hard coded

Tags: php, mysql, jstree

In my website, I have a drop down select option that lists databases available in MySQL.  Within each database, i have a table named tree.  Whenever the select option is changed to a new database, or page reload happens, I do a post of database name to a php file.

I am using the following scripts on my page:

```
<!-- Color CSS Styles  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>*/
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f87c84f770.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="lightslider.css"/>
    <script src="lightslider.js"></script> 
    <script src="jtree.js"></script>
```

The code to post the database name is as follows:

index.php

```
$.post('autorefreshtree.php', {'folder':wd}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

autorefreshtree.php

```
session_start();
include('connect.php');
$database = $_POST['folder'];
//$database="IPL2010";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$database );
if ($connect->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connection successful";
}

category_tree(0);
function category_tree($catid){
    global $connect;
    $sql = "select * from `tree` where `parentid` ='$catid'";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)):
        $i = 0;
        if ($i == 0) echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>' . $row->nodename;
            category_tree($row->tree_id);
            echo '</li>';
        $i++;
        if ($i > 0) echo '</ul>';
    endwhile;
    }

mysqli_close($connect);
```

When I run the code, I get the `Connection Successful` message logged on to console, the tree is getting generated, and the complete ul li parameters along with the data gets printed on to console.  However, the actual tree structure could not be seen.

[image]

When I make the following change in my autorefreshtree.php:

```
//$database = $_POST['folder'];
$database="IPL2010";
```

hard code the database name, both the tree is displayed as well as the console output could be seen.

[image]

The following is the display logic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wd = localStorage.getItem('wd');
  $.post('autorefreshtree.php', {'folder':wd}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
})



//Function to autorefresh tree
 var requestUrl = 'autorefreshtree.php';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#annotateDirectories").jstree({
           'core' : {
                'data' : {
                  'url' : requestUrl,
                }
            },
            "checkbox": {   
                "keep_selected_style" : true,
                'tie_selection' : false,        
                'two_state' : true
            },
            'plugins': ['wholerow','search','contextmenu','checkbox','state','sort']
        });
    });

    (function(){ 
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:requestUrl,
          datatype:"html",
          success:function(data) {
              $('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).settings.core.data = data;
              $('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).load_data('#');
          }
        });
    });


//Function to retain the checked status of tree
var selectedBox = sessionStorage.getItem("annotateDirectories");  
  $('#annotateDirectories').val(selectedBox);
  $('#annotateDirectories').change(function() { 
      var dropval = $(this).val();
      sessionStorage.setItem("annotateDirectories", dropval);
});
```

Comment: Try changing the line ```if ($connect->connect_error) {``` to ```if(!$connect) {``` to see if the connection is valid.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thank you...I am still getting connection successful...without the tree.

Comment: It must be an issue somewhere in your Javascript code.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have commented out all JS codes from the page, but strangely the same problem still persists.

Comment: If you truely commented out all of the JS code, no tree would be displayed unless you're using a css-only based tree.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the logic reason should be $_POST['folder'] is empty, i.e., wd is empty.

You connection to database is successful because your host, user and password is correct, but database is empty so that no database is selected.

I hope this code is not in production, but even in practice, you shouldn't query database in a loop.

jstree can be constructed by just a list of node and parent_node.

Comment: Thank you...when I echo `$_POST['folder']`, I get the right output, and is not empty...so is wd....when I use an alert, I get the alert with the right values....besides the same wd post for some other php query, works perfectly

Comment: I misunderstood your issue. The data is already outputed to client, so it's must be in the javascript. Can you post your display logic?

Comment: Thank you...I have added additional codes...that displays to the div `annotatedDirectories`

Comment: Your jstree ajax request is a GET request, so that your $_POST["wd"] for the jstree request is empty, although your debug request is POST.

Comment: Whether I have post or get, the database connection is successful however I realized the function category tree has is working selectively.  Just couldn't understand.  With the same connection if I just print the values from the table tree, they work without an issue.

Comment: You have two different Ajax to the same URL, one by post and one by get. The post one is print to console and it works, while the get one is the one you display the jstree and it will fail. This explains why you change to hardcode will work